# Getting into competition math for an eager to learn high school student

Tags: contest-math

I recently moved countries, and am now in a US school. Previously, I've had a little bit of exposure to competition math, and I did okay, but at this time I wasn't diving very deep into math in general, much less competition math.

Today, it's a bit different. I've come to conclude that math is a highly fascinating subject, and am thus looking to trade breadth for depth, and really focus my efforts somewhere. With the opportune change of scenery, I decided I would get into competition math (as I did find it interesting in the past).

Here's my question: where do I start? It's not so straightforward as, say, learning a specific topic or subject. I've been working through old competition problems, studying some common areas that come up (currently working on number theory), and so on. To be blunt, I have no idea what I'm doing, so I decided I would get to the drawing board and map out the general trajectory for the short/mid/long-term, so I know just what it is I'm going at. So, I turn to you.

Thank you very much for reading this. I would like nothing more than to learn from you, anything and everything you might have to say to me is welcome. Thanks once again.

Comment: There's a whole website just for you! artofproblemsolving.com

Comment: Definitely check out artofproblemsolving.com.

Comment: Thank you Don Thousand and littleO! I've just finished looking through a portion of the resources AoPS provides. It's a goldmine. I have a question, though: How do I map out a cohesive/coherent plan for progress (short/mid/long-term)? I started with some AMC 10/12 problems, but I realized I should think about the bigger picture first. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, www.mathlinks.ro

Answer (score 1):

Talk to your math teacher(s) and consult [this site](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=List_of_United_States_high_school_mathematics_competitions).